# program to insert into a string at a selected index

Tags: python, list, input

I am trying to write code that:

1. asks user to input a string .
2. then asks user to select an index
3. then asks the user to select a character.
4. then changes the string by adding a character to the index that was selected. Thanks

PYTHON

```
string1=[]

string1 = input(str("input string: "))
print(string1)

index = input("select index: ")
add_char = input(str("add char: "))

string1 = string1.insert(index, add_char)
print(string1)
```

Comment: Strings are immutable, you can't modify them with `insert()`. Use slices and concatenation.

Comment: You need to convert `index` to an `int`.

Comment: You also don't need to wrap your quotes in a `str()` constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings don't have an `insert()` method because they're immutable.

You can convert the string to a list, insert the new character into the list, then convert that back to a string with `join()`.

```
string1 = input("input string: ")
index = int(input("select index: "))
add_char = input("add char: ")

string_list = list(string1)
string_list.insert(index, add_char)
string1 = "".join(string_list)
print(string1)
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar - much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, as a function:

```py
def str_insert(string, char, index):
    return string[:index] + char + string[index:]

print(str_insert("Test String", "W", 4)) # "TestW String"
```

Comment: Thanks Keldan - much appreciated